# Ошибка в первой букве else на питоне(python 3.9.5)

Tags: python

```
b2 = input ('число от 0 до 10')
    if b2: 5
    print('ошибка')
    else:
    True
    if(False):
    for b2 in
```

else:
^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: :D А вы точно понимаете, что вы пишите? Вы же просто рандомный текст написали.

Comment: Почему? Что не так?

Comment: p.s.: понял что не так в input , но все ровно есть ошибка в else, и я не знаю от чего она

Comment: В питоне очень важны отступы. Ниже в ответах примеры правильных отступов

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
b2 = input ('число от 0 до 10')
if b2 == '5'
    print('ошибка')
else:
    flag = True
if not(flag):
    for b2 in #тут недописанный цикл, но я уверен вы с ним справитесь и сами
```

Answer (score -1):

У тебя нарушены отступы
как то так оно должно быть

```
b2 = input ('число от 0 до 10')
if (b2: 5):
    print('ошибка')
else:
    if(False):
       for b2 in
```

Comment: но тогда у тебя будет ошибка в цикле

Comment: авторский посыл программы упущен) Вы упустили создание булевой переменной, она ведь на что то должна влиять, хотя соглашусь, сути программы я не понимаю, но думаю, должны быть примерно как в моем ответе

Comment: Спасибо за помощь, я хотел сделать программу которая бы запрашивала цифру от 1 до 10 у пользователя , далее если бы он выбирал 5 то должна писаться ошибка и запрашивать снова цифру. Но так как только начинаю от того и ошибки по типу неправильного использования input,непонимания общего синтаксиса и т.д.